# Data not saving into database using sqlite c# xamarin forms

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I am trying to save into SQLite database but it does not write into it. while I debugged, the text property of my entries is set to the text I entered at Run-time but on saving into the database, the values are set to null and returns nothing to my ListView. Below is my model for my database:

```
  public class Products : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private string  _Itemname;
    private string _Details;


    [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(30)] [NotNull]
    public string Itemname {
        get
        {
            return _Itemname; 
        }
        set
        {
            if(_Itemname ==  value)
            return;

            _Itemname = value;

        }
    }

    public string ItemBrand { get; set; }

    [NotNull]
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Details {
        get
        {
            return _Details;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Details == value)
                return;
            _Details = value;
        }
    }

    public string Category { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public string Supplier { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyname=null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }
```

The below code is my addButton c# code:
      MyConnection = DependencyService.Get().connection();

```
        //CreateTable();
        BindingContext = new Products
        {
            Itemname = ItemNameTextBox.Text,
            ItemBrand = ItemBrandTextBox.Text,
            Date = DateTextBox.ToString(),
            Details = DetailsTextBox.Text,
            Category = CategoryTextBox.ToString(),
            Supplier = SupplierTextBox.Text,
            Price = PriceTextBox.Text,
            Quantity = QuantityTextBox.Text
        };
    }

    private async void SaveItemButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var a = BindingContext as Products;
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ItemNameTextBox.Text)|| string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ItemBrandTextBox.Text)|| string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SupplierTextBox.Text)
            || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PriceTextBox.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(QuantityTextBox.Text))
        {
           await DisplayAlert("Invalid Command", "Fields cannot be empty", "Ok");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            await MyConnection.InsertAsync(a);
            ProductAdded?.Invoke(this, a);

            await DisplayAlert("Yay!!!", "Product added successfully....", "Ok");
           var result= await  DisplayAlert("Additional Prompt", "Do you want to add another product?", "Yes", "No");

            if (result) {               ItemBrandTextBox.Text = "";
            ItemNameTextBox.Text = "";
            DetailsTextBox.Text = "";
            SupplierTextBox.Text = "";
            PriceTextBox.Text = "";
            QuantityTextBox.Text = "";}
            else
            {
             await   Navigation.PopAsync();
            }
```

Comment: Is the text property somehow linked to the object? You check the controls and their properties, but how about the object you send to be saved in the database? What are the values there?

Comment: have you actually examined the db with an SQLite tool to verify that nothing is being saved?  Its possible that the data is saved, but there is a problem with how you load/bind the data, so that you are never seeing it

Comment: hey Sami, I am entering data into the database via the various controls on the page. I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @jason. i havent heard about any sqlite tool to check that. would u recommend one to me so i can verify its really not saving in the database

Comment: https://sqlitebrowser.org/, there are many others

Comment: okay thanks. i will check that out and does it come with how to use?